# Balanced brackets

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to check if brackets are balanced or not by using stack for example if I entered (()) for every opened bracket there's a closed one  there fore it's balanced;
but every time cout is not balanced.
I can't find what's wrong with my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct node
{
    char data ;
    node* link;

};

bool pop(node*&top,char val)
{
    if(top==NULL)
        return false; 
    else
        val=top->data;
    node* temp=top;
    top=top->link;
    delete temp;
    return true;


}
bool push (node*&top,char val)
{
    node* nptr=new node;
    if(nptr==NULL)
        return false;
    nptr->data=val;
    nptr->link=top;
    top=nptr;
    return true;


}
bool balancedbracket(char *s,int size1)

{

node* k;
if (s[0]==')')
{
    return false;
}

for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
{
    if(s[i]=='(')
    {
    push(k,'(');
    }
    else if (s[i]==')')
        {
            pop(k,'(');
            }

}

        if (k==NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }




    }


int main()
{
    char *a=new char;
    int sizeofmyarray;
    cout<<"enter size:";
    cin>>sizeofmyarray;
    cout<<"enter array:";
    for(int i=0;i<sizeofmyarray;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    if(balancedbracket(a,sizeofmyarray))
        cout<<"is balanced";
    else
        cout<<"not balanced";


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Your `{`/`}` are balanced in terms that for each `{` there is a closing `}`. This, however, does not mean that your _encapsulation_ is correct (syntactically and/or logically). It is custom to exploit **indentation** to make code more clear, specially when you have hierarchy of **blocks** like in your case.

Comment: IHe was talking about task of program, not the parenthesis in the code XD

Comment: People, do not downvote  silly question just because it is silly. He actually asked  for help and gave everything required to solve his problem.  It's obviously a student work, they never were taught how to debug  at first steps, pushing them into sea of mysterious code with leaky tub and slipper  instead of oar. I know, I was there 20 years ago.

Comment: @Swift `char *a=new char;` says minimal research was performed. How to allocate dynamic arrays is covered early in any programming text that isn't outright fraudulent. And if I get really pedantic, the question is missing an MCVE. The problem could be duplicated in a couple lines of code.

Comment: You'll be surprised. Teachers do that kind of stuff. Yes, they didn't research each code line, probably it was taken from somewhere else. In my case only research possible was book full of as you say fraudulent code (I still have it, showing people to tell them not to trust that). There was no internet at the time though

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating only one character in main():

```
char *a=new char;
```

and later you are corrupting your heap with

```
   cin>>a[i];
```

with each i > 0.

You should allocate some maximum amount of chars:

```
 int main()
{
    char a[1000];
    int sizeofmyarray;
    cout<<"enter size:";
    cin>>sizeofmyarray;
    if (sizeofmyarray > 1000) {
        cout<<"too big";
        return -1;
    }
    cout<<"enter array:";
    for(int i=0;i<sizeofmyarray;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    if(balancedbracket(a,sizeofmyarray))
        cout<<"is balanced";
    else
        cout<<"not balanced";

}
```

Comment: May I suggest suggesting `std::vector` instead of the fixed-size array?

Comment: @user4581301, yes, std::vector would be way to go, but OP has much to learn, I thought this would better point out the original bug.

Comment: yes, that's one of mistakes in that code along with checking if new  failed by value of pointer. Actually, in debug build ALL that would work, but actual bug in algorithm was that he didn't set k to NULL at beginning

Answer (score 0):

It's simple mistake, **you did not actually set node pointer k to zero (NULL)** in beginning so you'll end with non-zero pointer and you treat it as sign of state "not balanced".
`delete` doesn't set pointer to NULL either. ***delete and delete[] DO NOT set its argument to zero.*** It's so because argument can be a result of pointer arithmetic, for example when referencing an array.

You do not have enough memory to store array:

```
int main()
{

    int sizeofmyarray;
    cout<<"enter size:";
    cin>>sizeofmyarray;
    char *a=new char[sizeofmyarray];
```

Better use  a string or vector.. something like that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

struct node
{
    char data ;
    node* link;
};

bool pop(node* &top, char val)
{
    if(top==NULL)
        return false; 
    else
        val=top->data;
    node* temp=top;
    top=top->link;
    delete temp;
    return true;
}

bool push (node* &top, char val)
{
    node* newtop;
    try {
        newtop = new node;  
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc&) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    newtop->data=val;
    newtop->link=top;
    top=newtop;
    return true;
}

bool balancedbracket(string s)
{  
    node* k = NULL;  //!!! never leave it uninitialized
    if (s[0]==')')
        return false;

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='(')
        {
            push(k,'(');
        }
        else if (s[i]==')')
        {
            pop(k,'(');  // do we really need this argument?
        }

    }

    return k==NULL;
}

int main()
{   
    string str;
    cout << "enter array:";
    std::getline(cin,str);

    if(balancedbracket(str))
        cout<<"is balanced\n";
    else
        cout<<"not balanced\n";

    system("pause");
}
```

There are few other gotchas I addressed there and code isn't  a best implementation still, but there are some useful ones. For example it's not recommended to pull entire namespace

The only  true algorithmic error was here: `node* k;` in `balancedbracket()`
The original program with `node* k = NULL;` will work, yet it WOULD corrupt its memory, but until it reaches end of redzone, no segfault\exception-5 will be raised.

```
enter size:6
enter array:(.)(.)
is balancedДля продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

enter size:6
enter array:(())((
not balancedДля продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```